# Accessing NS Type class category in swift-3

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I've `NSData` category for `base64Encoding` written in Obj-C.

```
@interface NSData (Base64)

+ (NSData*)dataFromBase64String:(NSString*)aString;
- (NSString*)base64EncodedString;

@end
```

Initially in Swift 2.2, I was using it as:

```
let dbPassData = NSData(fromBase64String: password)
```

Now, in Swift 3, there is no any `NSData`, instead have `Data`.

**How to use these category methods in swift 3?**

---

After converting project to Swift 3, it converted that line as:

```
let dbPassData = Data(fromBase64String: password)
```

which yields an error:

> Argument labels do not match any available overloads

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, Apple also renamed some initializers and Xcode 8 beta makes some mistakes when converting from 2.2 to 3.

In that case, the initializer was renamed to this:

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: "hello")
```

---

When you are facing this or similar problems, you can start typing `ClassName(` and look at the proposed initializers. In most cases, you'll find the new one easily.

Answer (score 0):

`NSData` is still available in Swift 3, just like `String` has been coexisting with `NSString`. You need to ignore the compiler's advice in this case:

```
let dbPassData = NSData(fromBase64String: password) as Data
```

This assumes you don't want to port your `Base64` category to Swift or you want to maintain compatibility with Obj-C code. Swift 3's `Data` also offer built-in Base 64 conversion:

```
let dbPassData   = Data(base64Encoded: password)
let base64String = data.base64EncodedString(options: [.lineLength64Characters, .endLineWithLineFeed])
```